# const page = window.location.pathname + string

Tags: javascript

Using the below code I can to apply `${post}` when the pathname matches `/post`

```
 const post =
 window.location.pathname === '/post'
```

But how can I achieve this to any **wild** paths that contain `/post/` but also extend the path with a string such as `/post/1` and `/post/2`?

I was really hoping that it was going to be as easy as adding `*`, yet it is not.

Comment: You can use the function  `pathname.includes('post')` to check if your pathname includes the word 'post'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try checking if the path includes a certain substring.

```
if(window.location.pathname.includes('/post/')){

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Cheers. I'll accept this when it allows in a few minutes.